# Jenkins Analysis stage won't finish due to Sonar issue?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

```
[Pipeline] sh
14:37:02 + curl -s -k -u ********: https://sonarqube.....

[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
14:37:02 Found branch info: [name:feature/X.X/random-branch-name, isMain:false, type:SHORT, mergeBranch:master, status:[qualityGateStatus:OK, bugs:0, vulnerabilities:0, codeSmells:0], analysisDate:2022-07-07T12:10:34+0000]

[Pipeline] echo
14:37:02 Analysis for this pipeline run hasn't finished yet: Thu Jul 07 14:10:34 CEST 2022 < Thu Jul 07 14:10:36 CEST 2022

[Pipeline] sh
14:37:02 + sleep 15s

[Pipeline] echo
14:37:17 Looking for analysis result in SonarQube Community (https://sonarqube....)...
```

It's in a loop for several hours and just wont finish.

Comment: It's in a loop for several hours and just wont finish.

Comment: Add timeout to this stage, you Jenkins function for it

Answer (score 0):

The details you provided are too short but I would say to take it step by step:

1. Check if in the previous stage the scan is successfully done and uploaded to SonarQube server
2. Check what is that function actually looking for to check the status of the scan because it will make a "(1==0)" will keep it running forever